# How do I create a custom write accessor when using Moose?

Tags: perl, moose, accessor

**Edit**: Answer added below, question left here for historical purposes only.

[Moose documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1005/lib/Moose/Manual/Attributes.pod#Accessor_methods) states that:

> If you want, you can also explicitly specify the method names to be
>   used for reading and writing an attribute's value. This is
>   particularly handy when you'd like an attribute to be publicly
>   readable, but only privately settable. For example:
>
> ```
> has 'weight' => (
>   is     => 'ro',
>   writer => '_set_weight',   
>  );
> ```
>
> This might be useful if weight is calculated based on other methods.
>   For example, every time the eat method is called, we might adjust
>   weight. This lets us hide the implementation details of weight
>   changes, but still provide the weight value to users of the class.

Based on this example, I wrote the following code:

```
has '_current_url' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'URI',
    writer => '_write_URI_to_current_url',
);

# Thus we ensure only a URI object gets written to current_url always
sub _current_url
{
    my $self = shift;
    $self->_write_URI_to_current_url(URI->new_abs($_[0], $self->start_url));
}
```

My intention was to ensure that setting current_url always sets it to a URI object even if it was called with a simple string. However, when I try to run the code, I get:

> Cannot assign a value to a read-only accessor of _current_url

at the place (within my class) where I'm trying to set the current_url (with `$self->_current_url($str);`).

This is my second day with Moose so I'm quite confused as to what's going on here. To my understanding the `is => 'ro'` only asks Moose not to create a default write accessor with the same name as the attribute, is that understanding correct? How can I achieve my goal here?

Comment: For what you're doing here, what you really want is to investigate types and type coercions.  You don't need a custom writer, you need a custom coercion.

Comment: @cjm Coercion is the first thing I tried, but the problem is the type change's `via` depends on a second parameter `$self->start_url` which Moose didn't like, so that resulted in an error. Does the sub in `via` get passed a copy of $self, and is it possible to use a different attribute for the coercion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I believe I've found the issue.

The `_current_url` method I've pasted above got overridden by Moose's generated read-only accessor of the same name, so when I tried to call `$self->_current_url` with a value, it throws the above error to indicate that the read-only accessor cannot set values.

I guess the error message should ideally be `Cannot assign a value **through** a read-only accessor of _current_url`, not `**to** a  read-only accessor`.

Changing the name of the sub to `_set_current_url` solved the problem. I guess another way to achieve the same would be to tell Moose that `_current_url` `is => 'rw'` and then create an `around '_current_url'`. I haven't tried this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game but just saw this post and ran into the same thing a while back.  '_set_current_url' really seems like an attribute accessor instead of an attribute.  Might want to consider:

```
has '_current_url' => {
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'URI',
  writer => 'set_current_url',
  reader => 'get_current_url'
  }
```

A bit cleaner this way since the attribute is the original '_current_url' and you have accessors to get/set the attribute.

Comment: My understanding was that `writer` and `reader` options change the name of the auto-created accessors, is that incorrect? If it's correct, auto-creating a writer with the name `set_current_url` doesn't sound useful in this case since the point is to customize the write accessor, am I missing something?

Comment: The auto-created accessor is '_current_url'.  If you remove 'writer' and 'reader' from the 'has' statement, you can get/set the attribute using '_current_url' (i.e. $object->_current_url).  When you use writer/reader, it disables access to the attribute with '_current_url' and requires you to use 'set_current_url' and 'get_current_url'.